# Preview files in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: files, 15.10

In the Ubuntu desktop guide it is advertised that in Ubuntu 15.10 it is possible to see a preview of files and folders by pressing the space bar (just like in Mac OS X).

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 but I cannot preview any of my files. Do I have to enable this option, and if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you have to install a previewer. Take a look here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/enable-nautilus-file-preview-ubuntu-14-10-14-04/

Comment: It's a new feature in Ubuntu 15.10. No need to install any other third-party app.

Comment: @TungTran I was not aware of that. Why it does not work then. It doesn't work in my Ubuntu 15.10 too.

Comment: @TungTran It doesn't work in my Ubuntu 15.10 either, and it should if it is a new feature. So far what I had to do was to install either **gnome-sushi** or **gloobus-preview**. However I am not too happy with either (far from being the same as preview in Mac), but from the two I prefer **gnome-sushi**.